# How to include empty string in a like query in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

This seems an easy thing but somehow I'm not able to think of it.

I want to write a like query in this format:

```
WHERE Searchfield LIKE '[ ;]Mark'
```

Now this would check for an occurence of

```
' Mark', ';Mark'
```

I want it to be able to search the following string as well:

```
'Mark'
```

How do I indicate that it can have the occurrence of a space, or a semicolon or no character.

Comment: Why are you allowing junk data into your table? Why don't you clean it on the way in instead of having to come up with cumbersome clauses to deal with it later?

Comment: Its not about having junk data.. The string i showed is part of a searchfield which is created by concatenating many column values using a delimiter.
So, my searches have to be wild card searches.. And I want exact word search. So, 'Mark;;abc;;def;;ijk', 'abc;;Mark;;def;;ijk' and 'abc;;Mark John;;cde;;' etc. would be my sample searchfield values

Answer (score 5):

Probably easiest to just use

```
WHERE Searchfield LIKE '[ ;]Mark' OR  Searchfield = 'Mark'
```

If `Searchfield` is indexed then you might find that

```
WHERE Searchfield IN ('Mark', ' Mark', ';Mark')
```

gives you a better plan. There is no equivalent in the `Like` pattern syntax to a regular expression optional character class. Though you could use CLR regular expressions and the following regular expression `[ ;]?Mark`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I probably will have to use the OR option because I need to have the wild card options because of the reason mentioned in my reply to Aaron Bertrand above. Thanks.. Will try implementing it.

Comment: If there is only three versions of the string that you want to match, use the "IN" clause.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the kind of thing fulltext was designed for.  If its a common query call, Use fulltext search.  Then your search term will simply be 'Mark'.

Comment: Yup. U guessed it, right? It was designed for full text. But I've to use Like query when wildchars are used in the beginning. For eg. for a string like '"Mark" *John' where Mark has to be an exact match and John has to get a %John match.